# Flutter call setState after Get.back()

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-getx

I need to reload page after Get.back(). How to do it? How to call any method on previous page as soon as possible after using Get.back()?
For example:

1. I'm on `Page1`
2. Go to `Page2`
3. Use Get.back(), so user back to `Page1`
4. Usually user now see `Page1` exactly like when he leave `Page1`. How to reload now view `Page1`?

Maybe is any method to override what I can call every time after navigate one page back? This method must come from `Page1`, not from `Page2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do await while navigating to page 2.

Example:

```
await Get.to(()=> Page2());
setState({
   // perform update
});
```

the setState will get fired once you come back to page 1 from page 2

another, similar example, code from Page1:

```dart
ListTile(
   title: const Text("Item"),
   onTap: () async {
      await Get.toNamed(page2);
      setState(() {});
   }),
```

Using this sample, refresh (`setState`) fired after return from Page2 to Page1.

Answer (score 2):

on Page 2:  You need to write this

```
Get.back(result: true);
```

on Page 1: wait for response

```
var response = await Get.to(()=> Page2());
if(response){setState({
   // perform update
});}
```